# Hide logo in header on first slider. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, swiper.js

Im working on a website that has header(top), slider(middle) and footer(bottom). On my first slide i have a logo showing so i'm wondring if it's possible to hide logo on my header when my slider is on first slide, **but only hidden on first slide** and when i'm on other slides that a logo still shows on a header.

I'm using a slider "Swiper" if that helps.

Link to a website is:
http://raumfuerkunsttherapie.de/FW/

Any help will be much appreciated!
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can using the `nth-selector` property of CSS. Each slide inside your slider has a common class `swiper-slide` so you can target the logo image inside the first slide like this and then hide it using `display: none;`:

```
.swiper-slide:first-child .row .u-max-full-width {
    display: none;
}
```

Using the above CSS will hide the logo image on the first slide but it'll appear on the rest of the slides.

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply @FahadHasan :)
I guess i didn't expres my self very well cause of my english. What i meant is that if it's possible, when first slide is active that my logo **in header** is hidden (cause i have logo already on first slide) and when i'm on slide 2 or else that my logo in header is visible.